# How to run minecraft?

Tags: minecraft

I am totally new to linux and am trying to run minecraft on it. i have tried to search the web but unfortunately dont quite understand. can some one please break it down a little simpler. thanks

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/q/225432/44179